# Angle between two quarters of ellipses

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

I must find the angle between two quarters of ellipses at their common point by the parametric equations:

$R_1(t) = 3\cos (t)i + \sin (t)j$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi/2$ and

$R2(s) = \cos (s)i + 3\sin (s)j$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi/2$

To get the point that they intersect, I solved the system of equations:

$3\cos(t)=\cos(s)$ and $\sin(s)=\frac13 \sin(t)$

which after my calculations, I obtained

$\cos(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$, $\sin(t)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$, $\cos(s)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$, and $\sin(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}
$.

Now I know that I have to get the tangents of both $R_1$ and $R_2$, which I can do very easily, but then what do I plug into the new tangent parameters? I am stuck here and would really appreciate any help in solving the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1):

on the ellipse at $R_1,$  the tangent has the slope $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\cos t}{3\sin t} = -\frac19 $$ in the same way on $R_2$ we have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -3\frac{\cos s}{\sin s} = -9 $$  let the angles these tangent make with the positive $x$-axis be $t, s.$  then we have $$\tan t = -1/9, \tan s = -9 \to \tan(t-s) = \frac{\tan t - \tan s}{1+\tan t \tan s}=\frac{9-1/9}{1+1} = \frac49 $$  therefore the angle between the tangent is $$ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac49\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have done it your work correctly so far, a far easier method would be to use implicit derivative to find the slope of the tangents at those intersection points. And then you can find the angles *separately*, then find their difference.